# Mysql version (0.3.11) doesn't ship with Activerecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a old rails project that is using rails 3.0.9 and I am trying to run it using rails s. It appears that when I do this is gives me the following error:

[image: Command prompt]

You will see that it says that the current adapter that I have installed is not supported by foriegner. I have updated my gemfile to look like the following:

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem "acl9"
gem 'foreigner'
gem 'devise'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'lazy_high_charts'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'tiny_mce'
#gem 'devise_security_extension'
#gem 'rails_email_validator'
#gem 'easy_captcha'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'jspec'
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'annotate'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc8'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'autotest-growl'
  gem 'autotest-rails'
  gem 'autotest', '4.4.6'
  gem 'autotest-rails-pure', '4.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'ZenTest'
  gem 'test-unit'
end
```

What I don't seem to understand is why it would say in the command prompt that the gem is missing and I need to add it to my gemfile when it is there. What is the best solution to tackling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isnt working cause you are trying to install the latest version of mysql2 which doesnt work with rails 3.0.X. You can get around this by specifying the version this way

gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3' or gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7"

But to get around the foreigner dependency which is probably the main issue here:

You can upgrade your rails version to 3.1.x or higher and upgrade the mysql2 in the gem file. I see that you have a recent version of ruby.

After you update the gems in the gemfile, make sure you run bundle install in the command line...before trying to start the server. Also, ensure that you setup your database in the database.yml file in the config folder.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clearer. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: I added the gem the way you suggested and did the bundle install and still receive the following: http://i.imgur.com/zcIpG.png

Comment: @Djj...you can specify the version you want by doing this gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7"...nonetheless, did you setup your database in the database.yml file? It looks like it cant connect to your database. Also you should know that you can simply upgrade your rails version to 3.1.x or higher and then upgrade the mysql2 version. This will get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

edit your config/database.yml file from:

```
adapter: mysql
```

to

```
adapter: mysql2
```